# Create RDBMS like sequence in Pig relation

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to create a sequence on a pig relation.

Say For example i have a relation with data:

```
(John, A-1)
(Jack, B-2)
(Jim, C-1)
```

I want to create sequence i.e to add one more column to the relation, like
a counter and keep on increasing the count for each record read. Exepected output should be something like this:

(If 200 is the start sequence. )

```
(John, A-1, 201)
(Jack, B-2, 202)
(Jim, C-1, 203)
```

How should i proceed on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can actually do that in a map/reduce since there's no global place where this sequence will be held and synchronized  - the different map instances each run on a separate server and you can not synchronize them (without significant pain anyway)